# Separate data in multiple rows using query

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have a data-set that came from python in my PSQL database, and I should not modify it internally, so I think its better to extract it and organize it with PSQL the way I need it to graph it.

The current data-set looks like:

```
text                                      contained_word_id
'I eat pizza in the park'                 2, 5
'I eat sushi'                             1
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  1, 2, 4
'He eats'                                 NaN
```

I would like to transform it into the following when I download it using a PSQL query:

```
text                                      contained_word_id
'I eat pizza in the park'                 2
'I eat pizza in the park'                 5
'I eat sushi'                             1
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  1
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  2
'She eats sushi with pizza in the plaza'  4
'He eats'                                 NaN
```

What is the best approach to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the awful comma separated list a list of rows using `regex_split_to_table` based on the comma:

```
select t.text, i.contained_word_id
from the_table t
  cross join regexp_split_to_table(t.contained_word_id, '\s*,\s*') as i(contained_word_id);
```